# Spring Reactor how to cache once and distribute response to all other users

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor

My application scrapes the currency data from a website for each 10 seconds.

I would like to cache the example currency data below:

ScrappedCurrency(base=EUR, target=USD, rate=1.2412)

And stream the data to all the others users from the following endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/currency", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<ScrappedCurrency> getCurrencyValuesRealTime() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .map(it -> webScrapper.scrap())
            .doOnNext(it -> log.info("[getCurrencyValues] Method is returned :: it={}", it));
}
```

When I call the webScrapper.scrap() for each users, I am creating an overloading for the scraped website unnecessarily since as far as I know each of the users that calls this endpoint are sending separate requests to the scraped website. If needed, I could also share the scraper code so please request in the comments.

Instead of doing this way, **I would like to call this scraper method once** and **distribute the response data to each of the users that calls that endpoint**. How can I implements this or is it possible in Spring Reactor? In addition, should I use some technology (i.e. Redis, Kafka) to achieve this or could I achieve it with only Reactor?

Domain clarification: There is not any memory concern about the problem since the number of items will be limited.

There will be around 20 of the following ScrappedCurrency objects and the same objects will be constantly updated. Therefore, the number of objects in the memory will remain the same which is 20.

What we desire is this: Read currency values (i.e. EUR/USD conversion) from a source. Update the data in the memory. Then, send the data to all the subscribers. While streaming the data to the subscribers, the previously read and updated data should be used for the streaming.

There must not be additional requests sent to the data source for each client. There will be only 1 request sent in each 10 seconds, and this data will be streamed. 10 seconds is a must for reading data. However, there is not any limitation for the subscribers.

Comment: `as far as I know each of the users that calls this endpoint are sending separate requests to the scraped website` please read the part about `hot vs cold` publishers in the reactor documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems like that Hot Publishers & ConnectedFlux are the solutions to my problem. However, I could not find any logical samples other than printing some random integers on the screen. Could you please provide an example code snippet?

Comment: no i can not provide a code snippet. There are several examples in the documentation, you will have to work off those, and come up with a solution that fits your demands.

Comment: Do you have any memory concerns? I mean if you want to replay all the Flux items, then after a couple of hours it will quickly get into the range of thousands. Can you share a bit more about your domain problem and what your client expect in the response. If you serve from cache then do you still need the 10 sec delay?

Comment: Probably that `scrap()` method could be `@Cacheable`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache

Comment: Hi @MartinTarjányi. I have added the domain clarification.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I will check it out then respond thank you.

Comment: You also can take a look into a `Sinks` API, e.g. `Sinks.many().replay()`: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processors

Comment: What I'm confused by is that based on your example code it seems that every scraper call returns only ONE exchange rate. How does it maintain state? How does it know what it returned before and what it needs to return next?

Comment: So if you can share some info about the scraper that might be useful.